# RabbitMQ using one queue for different tasks

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a one queue for CRUD. How to differ which operation is received (Add or Delete)? Is there any kind of routing for RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing is a fundamental aspect of RabbitMQ. You probably want a topic exchange. RabbitMQ provides some very good [tutorials](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html).